# Customized jQuery slider giving weird output in different browers

Tags: jquery, slider

I set some styles to make jQuery slider looks nice.Used image for ui-slider-handler.
I works fine in IE and google chrome. But its not working properly in Safari and Firefox.
I tried to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kXCCS/) it and checked the fiddled output in different browsers.It works fine then.

I am not getting why does it not work if the same source code is ran at my desktop(in broweres Safari and Firefox).I guess that script might be called at wrong place.I tried to call the script in different places though.
**Output in Different Browsers **

**Google Chrome**
[image]
**Firefox**
[image]
**Safari**
[image]
Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC>
    <html>
     <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

      <style>

      .vUiSliderWrapper{
        overflow:hidden;
      }
      .vUiSlider{
        height:7px;
        background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #b9b9b9,#e0e0e0);
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType="0",startColorStr="#b9b9b9",endColorStr="#e0e0e0");
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b9b9b9), to(#e0e0e0)) !important; 
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#b9b9b9,#e0e0e0) !important;
      }
      .vUiSlider .ui-slider-handle{
        border:none;
        background:url('http://s14.postimage.org/wo9hknojx/slider_handles.png') 0 -27px no-repeat;
        width:20px;
        height:17px;  
        outline: none;
      }
      .vUiSlider .ui-slider-handle:hover{
        background-position:0 -4px;
       }
      .vUiSlider .ui-slider-range{ 
        border-radius:4px;
        background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #04adff,#0083c1);
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType="0",startColorStr="#04adff",endColorStr="#0083c1");
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#04adff), to(#0083c1)) !important; 
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#04adff,#0083c1) !important;
      }

      #sld1 .vUiSlider{
       width:200px;
      }
      </style>
     </head>
    <body>
      <span id="sld1" class="vUiSliderWrapper">
       <div  class="vUiSlider"></div>
       <input type="text" role="data"/>
      </span>

     <span id="sld2" class="vUiSliderWrapper">
      <div class="vUiSlider"></div>
      <input type="text" role="data"/>
     </span>

      <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
           $('.vUiSliderWrapper .vUiSlider').slider({
             range: "min",
             min:0,
             max:100,
             value:3,
             animate: true,
             slide:function(event, ui){
                $(this).siblings('input[role="data"]').val(ui.value);
             }
           });
       });

      </script>
     </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve this problem by replacing `script` and `styles sheet`s with new version files.
But I am still wondering how could it work in `IE` and `Google Chrome` if files are older version.